# How to run Python program with realtime priority Linux

Tags: python, real-time, raspbian

I am writing a python program that is latency sensitive (taking stereo images simultanously from 2 cameras).

I am reading up on real time operating systems and I would like to run my python program with SCHED_FIFO or FF priority or something similar.  I am using Rasbian(debian) with RT_PREMPT kernal.

Is this the right approach? How do I run my python program with real time (SCHED_FIFO) priority?

attempt

> sudo chrt --rr 50 python3 loopExample.py

Answer (score 0):

In order to do true realtime operations, you might want to consider running a realtime Linux kernel. It can make a dramatic difference in terms of max latency and give you a more consistent response time, [as you can see from this benchmark test on the Pi](https://medium.com/@metebalci/latency-of-raspberry-pi-3-on-standard-and-real-time-linux-4-9-kernel-2d9c20704495)

You can get the Raspberry PI's version of the RealTime kernel [here](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/tree/rpi-4.14.y-rt). You will need to compile and install it, [this should help get you there](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/building-and-installing-the-latest-linux-kernel-from-source-6d8df5345980).

In terms of updating a process' priority under Linux, this is called the "nice" value. The range of values available is between -20 for highest priority and 19 for lowest. You can run your Python application with a set nice value at the time of invocation using `sudo nice -n -20 python app.py`

Comment: I am already running RT kernal Rasbian lite with RT_PREMPT downloaded from here https://github.com/guysoft/RealtimePi.  I think you also need to make your process real time even in RT kernal?

Comment: Oh, sorry I somehow missed that part. I think that honestly will make the biggest difference, but changing the `nice` value can also help, like I said. You might need to do some fiddling and benchmarking with it to find the right balance, but you should be good!